# XMPPFramework - How can I update my own avatar image?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, avatar

I am developing an application in that I want to update my avatar image. I am following `XEP-0153` guidelines to update my avatar image and I constructed an `NSXMLElement` correspond to the following code in `XEP-0153` and sent that element through `XMPPStream`.

```
<iq from='juliet@capulet.com' 
    type='set'
    id='vc1'>
  <vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'>
    <PHOTO>
      <TYPE>image/jpeg</TYPE>
      <BINVAL>
        Base64-encoded-avatar-file-here!
      </BINVAL>
    </PHOTO>
  </vCard>
</iq>
```

The server responses the following error:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="vc1" to="vvreddy50@gmail.com/83557F96">
<vCard xmlns="vcard-temp">
      <photo>
        <type>image/jpeg</type>
        <binval>Base64-encoded-avatar-file-here</binval>
      </photo>
</vCard>
<error code="500" type="wait">
      <internal-server-error xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">
      </internal-server-error>
</error>
</iq>
```

Instead of  `<iq to='juliet@capulet.com' type='result' id='vc1'/>`

Please can anyone post the code or the link related to update avatar image? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

```
- (void)updateAvatar:(UIImage *)avatar 
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(avatar);
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        XMPPvCardTempModule *vCardTempModule = [[XMPPHandler sharedInstance] xmppvCardTempModule];
        XMPPvCardTemp *myVcardTemp = [vCardTempModule myvCardTemp];
        [myVcardTemp setName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",name.text]];
        [myVcardTemp setPhoto:imageData];
        [vCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:myVcardTemp];
    });
}
```

Comment: What is XMPPHandler ?

Comment: XMPPHandler is your own class that holds the xmpp modules that you instantiate.

Comment: have you got solution for  'XMPPHandler' ?

Answer (score 3):

#import "XMPPvCardTemp.h"

```
   - (void)updateAvatar:(UIImage *)avatar{  
  NSData *imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(avatar,0.5);
        NSXMLElement *vCardXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"vCard" xmlns:@"vcard-temp"];
        NSXMLElement *photoXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"PHOTO"];
        NSXMLElement *typeXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"TYPE"stringValue:@"image/jpeg"];
        NSXMLElement *binvalXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"BINVAL" stringValue:[imageData1 base64Encoding]];

        [photoXML addChild:typeXML];
        [photoXML addChild:binvalXML];
        [vCardXML addChild:photoXML];
        XMPPvCardTemp *myvCardTemp = [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardTempModule]myvCardTemp];
        if (myvCardTemp) {
            [myvCardTemp setPhoto:imageData1];
            [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardTempModule] updateMyvCardTemp
             :myvCardTemp];

        }
        else{

            XMPPvCardTemp *newvCardTemp = [XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempFromElement:vCardXML];
            [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardTempModule] updateMyvCardTemp:newvCardTemp];
        }
     }
```

Comment: You should send xmpp element after                                              **[vCardXML addChild:photoXML]**

Answer (score 1):

From the [XMPP Core RFC](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#stanzas-error-syntax), `<error type='wait'>` means:

> retry after waiting (the error is temporary)

so your code should wait a while and re-send the request.

(This is assuming that you are actually sending a base64-encoded JPEG image as the `BINVAL` of your vCard. The reply from the server doesn't correspond to the request you say you sent, so I'm assuming you've edited both. It would be better to include the exact request and reply in your question, but truncate the base64-encoded image to a few characters for concision.)