# How can i get Friends vcard avtar photo xmpp ios

Tags: ios

How can i get Friends vcard avtar photo xmpp ios? please help me any one... thanks in advance

XMPPvCardTemp *myvCardTemp = [self xmppvCardTempModule];//check if exist or not

```
if (!myvCardTemp)//if not then create a new vcard
{
    NSXMLElement *vCardXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"vCard" xmlns:@"vcard-temp"];
    XMPPvCardTemp *newvCardTemp = [self.xmppvCardTempModule vCardTempFromElement:vCardXML];
    [newvCardTemp setNickname:userName];
    [self updateMyvCardTemp:newvCardTemp];
}

NSString *str = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:user_ID];

[self.xmppvCardTempModule fetchvCardTempForJID:str];
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227017/xmppframework-how-can-i-update-my-own-avatar-image may helpful.

Comment: hi Velmurugan, actually iam able to udate my avtar succefully. but now ineed to get friends avtar and show it in friends table view.Please help me out in this as iam completely new to xmpp.And thanks a lot for ur quick reply:0

Answer (score 0):

Initialize and activate xmppvCardAvatarModule Module.

```
- (void) fetchVCardFor:(NSString *)toUser
    {
        XMPPJID *myJID = [XMPPJID jidWithUser:[toUser stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""] domain:self.domain resource:self.resource];
        [self.xmppvCardTempModule fetchvCardTempForJID:myJID useCache:YES];
    }
```

You will get the results in IQ as follow:

```
   - (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
   {
      XMPPvCardTemp *vCardTemp = [XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempCopyFromIQ:iq];
      if (vCardTemp != nil)
      {
          [self _updatevCardTemp:vCardTemp forJID:[iq from]];
          return YES;
      }
      return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your friend VCard avatar image (if your friend already set there image) via XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject info.

```
-(UIImage*)GetFriendImage:(XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *)user {

    //Check user has image on XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject or  not.
    if (user.photo != nil) {
        return  user.photo;
    } else {

         //Retrive image from xmppvCardAvatarModule
        NSData *photoData = [[[self appDelegate] 
        xmppvCardAvatarModule] photoDataForJID:user.jid];

        //Check xmppvCardAvatarModule has image or not, if xmppvCardAvatarModule return nil means your friend not set there image, so return your any default image.  
        if (photoData != nil) {
           return [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
        } else {
           return [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImage"];
        }
    }
}
```

Here `[self appDelegate]` is define as

```
- (AppDelegate *)appDelegate {
   return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

I define my all xmpp object as property to AppDelegate.h file as

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) XMPPvCardAvatarModule *xmppvCardAvatarModule;
```

for VCard, import `#import "XMPPvCardAvatarModule.h"` file or else check if this file already imported in `#import "XMPPFramework.h"` file than ignore to reimport.

You may retrieve XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject “user object” using his JID ike this

```
XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[[self appDelegate] xmppRosterStorage]
                                           userForJID:userJID
                                           xmppStream:[[self appDelegate] xmppStream]
                                 managedObjectContext:[[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext_roster]];
```

And after that pass this user object to `GetFriendImage` to retrive friend image.